Hamiltonian path problem about neighbors
Suppose $G=(V,E)$ be a graph such that any $S \subseteq V$ satisfies
$$|\partial S| \geq \min\{n - |S|, 2|S| + 1\}$$
where $\partial S = \{v \in V \setminus S \mid \exists u \in S, (u,v) \in E\}$, and $n = |V|$. Prove that $G$ has a Hamiltonian path.
It's easy to consider the longest path $v_1\cdots v_k$, and if $k \leq \frac{2n+1}3$, we have $|\partial(V\setminus S)| \geq k$, which leads to a contradiction. But I don't know what I can do next, or there might be another way to solve this problem.

Can you define $n$?

@I Zuka I Sorry, $n$ is the number of vertices and I added it to the question.

Claim:$\;$If $G=(V,E)$ with $|V|\ge 3$ is a graph such that for all $S \subseteq V$ we have
$$
|\partial{S}|\ge\min\{n-|S|,2|S|+1\}
$$
where $n=|V|$ and
$$
\partial{S}=\{u\in V{\setminus}S{\,\,\mid\,}(u,s)\in E\;\text{for some}\;s\in S\}
$$
then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

Proof:

Assume the hypothesis.

To prove that $G$ is Hamiltonian, it suffices, by Dirac's Theorem, to show that
$\deg(v)\ge{\large{\frac{n}{2}}}$ for all $v\in V$.

Suppose instead that $\deg(v) < {\large{\frac{n}{2}}}$ for some $v\in V$.

Let $S=\{s\in V{\,\mid\,}d(s,v) > 1\}$.

First we compute $|S|$ . . .
\begin{align*}
V{\setminus}S&=
\{u\in V{\,\mid\,}d(u,v)\le 1\}
\\[4pt]
&=
\{u\in V{\,\mid\,}d(u,v)=0\}
\cup
\{u\in V{\,\mid\,}d(u,v)=1\}
\\[4pt]
&=
\{v\}
\cup
\{u\in V{\,\mid\,}d(u,v)=1\}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so
$$
|V{\setminus}S|=1+\deg(v)
$$
hence
$$
|S|=n-(1+\deg(v))=n-1-\deg(v)
$$

Next we bound $|\partial{S}|$ . . .

If $v\in\partial{S}$ then
\begin{align*}
&
(v,s)\in E\;\text{for some}\;s\in S
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
d(v,s)=1
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contrary to the definition of $S$.

Hence $v\not\in\partial{S}$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
u\in\partial{S}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
u\in V{\setminus}S
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
d(u,v)\le 1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
d(u,v)=0
\;\text{or}\;
d(u,v)=1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
u=v
\;\text{or}\;
d(u,v)=1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
d(u,v)=1
\qquad
\bigl(
\text{since $v\not\in\partial{S}$}
\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $|\partial{S}|\le\deg(v)$.

But then
\begin{align*}
n-|S|
&=
n-(n-1-\deg(v))
\\[4pt]
&=
\deg(v)+1
\\[4pt]
&{\, > \,}
|\partial{S}|
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and also
\begin{align*}
2|S|+1
&=
2(n-1-\deg(v))+1 
\\[4pt]
&=
2n-1-2\deg(v)
\\[4pt]
&{\, > \,}
2n-1-n
\\[4pt]
&=
n-1
\\[4pt]
&\ge
\deg(v)
\\[4pt]
&\ge
|\partial{S}|
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence
$$
|\partial{S}| < \min\{n-|S|,2|S|+1\}
$$
contradiction.

This completes the proof.
